# Recursive Feature Elimination (RFE) SKLearn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I created a table to test my understanding

```
    F1  F2  Outcome
0   2   5        1
1   4   8        2
2   6   0        3
3   9   8        4
4  10   6        5
```

From F1 and F2 I tried to predict Outcome

As you can see F1 have a strong correlation to Outcome,F2 is random noise

I tested

```
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
fit = pca.fit(X)
print("Explained Variance")
print(fit.explained_variance_ratio_)
Explained Variance
[ 0.57554896  0.42445104]
```

Which is what I expected and shows that F1 is more important

However when I do RFE (Recursive Feature Elimination)

```
model = LogisticRegression()
rfe = RFE(model, 1)
fit = rfe.fit(X, Y)
print(fit.n_features_)
print(fit.support_)
print(fit.ranking_)
1
[False  True]
[2 1]
```

It asked me to keep F2 instead? It should ask me to keep F1 since F1 is a strong predictor while F2 is random noise... why F2?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `LogisticRegression` model. This is a classifier, not a regressor. So your outcome here is treated as labels (not numbers). For good training and prediction, a classifier needs multiple samples of each class. But in your data, only single row is present for each class. Hence the results are garbage and not to be taken seriously.

Try replacing that with any regression model and you will see the outcome which you thought would be.

```
model = LinearRegression()
rfe = RFE(model, 1)
fit = rfe.fit(X, y)

print(fit.n_features_)
print(fit.support_)
print(fit.ranking_)

# Output
1
[ True False]
[1 2]
```

Comment: Great I didnt noticed that it was a classifier... thanks bro

Comment: @JNg Also one more thing. In the PCA() you did there, you are looking at it wrong. PCA is used to transform the data into some other dimension in which learning is easy than current form. So it cannot tell you the feature importance. You can see that you havent supplied `y` in that. The explained variance is not importance. Its how much the data varies in that column.

Comment: Hi Vivek was wondering about the PCA, if it Explained Variance is high, it should mean that that factor is more meaningful to be use than other factors, thus more important?

Comment: @JNg No. Please understand that PCA will first convert your features to some other values and then find the variance. The explained variance you are seeing is not of your actual feature but a tranformed, projected components version of mixture of both of your original features. Its mostly used for feature reduction where you have many features and want to reduce them to maybe 2 or 3. Then the variance array will only have 2 or 3 values based on your new projected features and not original ones. Maybe you are getting confused because your output features are also 2 just as your input.

Comment: Please see the examples and documentation of PCA here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html

Comment: Hi Vivek thanks for your explanation, one more question please, thus if I have for example 10 factors, but I only want to keep 5 most useful ones, I should just do RFE (Recursive Feature Elimination)?

Comment: @JNg You can try both PCA and RFE and see what gives good results in your case. PCA will transform the data so maybe its easier for models to work with new data and classify them better. RFE will try to reduce the complexity of the model. Please see the user guide for both in scikit.

Answer (score 5):

It is advisable to do a Recursive Feature Elimination Cross Validation (RFECV) before running the Recursive Feature Elimination (RFE)

Here is an example:
Having columns :

```
df.columns = ['age', 'id', 'sex', 'height', 'gender', 'marital status', 'income', 'race']
```

Use RFECV to identify the optimal number of features needed.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rfe = RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 32) # Instantiate the algo
rfecv  = RFECV(estimator= rfe, step=1, cv=StratifiedKFold(2), scoring="accuracy") # Instantiate the RFECV and its parameters
fit = rfecv.fit(features(or X), target(or y))
print("Optimal number of features : %d" % rfecv.n_features_)
>>>> Optimal number of output is 4
```

Now that the optimal number of features has been known, we can use Recursive Feature Elimination to identify the Optimal features

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
min_features_to_select = 1
rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
rfe = RFE(estimator=rfc, n_features_to_select= 4, step=1)
fittings1 = rfe.fit(features, target)
for i in range(features.shape[1]):
    print('Column: %d, Selected %s, Rank: %.3f' % (i, rfe.support_[i], rfe.ranking_[i]))

output will be something like:
>>> Column: 0, Selected True, Rank: 1.000
>>> Column: 1, Selected False, Rank: 4.000
>>> Column: 2, Selected False, Rank: 7.000
>>> Column: 3, Selected False, Rank: 10.000
>>> Column: 4, Selected True, Rank: 1.000
>>> Column: 5, Selected False, Rank: 3.000
```

Now display the features to remove based on recursive feature elimination done above

```
columns_to_remove = features.columns.values[np.logical_not(rfe.support_)]
columns_to_remove

output will be something like:
>>> array(['age', 'id', 'race'], dtype=object)
```

Now create your new dataset by dropping the un-needed features and selecting the needed one

```
new_df = df.drop(['age', 'id', 'race'], axis = 1)
```

Then you can cross validation to know how well this newly selected features (new_df) predicts the target column.

```
# Check how well the features predict the target variable using cross_validation
cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
scores = cross_val_score(RandomForestClassifier(), new_df, target, cv= cv)

print("%0.2f accuracy with a standard deviation of %0.2f" % (scores.mean(), scores.std()))
>>> 0.84 accuracy with a standard deviation of 0.01
```

Don't forget you can also read up on the best Cross-Validation (CV) parameters to use in this [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html)

Recursive Feature Elimination (RFE) [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html) to learn more and understand better

Recursive Feature Elimination Cross validation (RFECV) [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html)